# rendering array of data in php view from controller

Tags: php

I have been trying for hours trying different methods to render the array element return by controller
like this way in view
[view snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grbxA.png)

but I am unable to render it , it gives this error
[error snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBZPW.png)
please help

Comment: It seems that the 'problems offset' doesn'st exist. Would you 'var_dump()' the $report var to see her structure?

Comment: please share your controller code while posting question

Comment: i was going to add the controller snap also, but due to my low reputation i wasn't able to do so,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IT is `laravel` i guess

first you need to check the format of $report (it would be better if you send us the $report structure)

i think it sends `array objects`

if it sends `array objects` use like

```
{{$URL->problems}}
```

Comment: thanks, I had tried that also, and i got solution without using php tag, and only with @foreach tag, using your solution.

Comment: I cant , i need 15 reputation,

Comment: sorry mate ...i dont know how this stackoverflow works...its just 1 week for me..... so dont know much abt it